# Space complexity for divide-and-conquer

Tags: recurrence-relation, recursion, space-complexity, divide-and-conquer

Here's a simple question but I'm not sure there is a simple answer. This came up in an undergraduate algorithms class.

Consider the following divide-and-conquer algorithm $A$ (here, $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are bits; assume $n$ is a power of 2 for convenience):

$A(x_1, ..., x_n)$:

- if $n=1$ then return $x_1$
- Else return $A(x_1, ..., x_{n/2}) \vee A(x_{n/2+1}, ..., x_n)$

What is the correct recurrence for the space complexity $S(n)$ of $A$ as a function of $n$? Some choices:

1. $S(n) = S(n/2) + O(n)$ since the recursive calls to $A$ require writing $O(n)$ elements as the input to $A$.
2. $S(n) = S(n/2) + O(\log n)$ since if $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are stored in memory that we can recursively call $A$ by reference (rather than by value) and so simply pass pointers as input to $A$ using $O(\log n)$ space.
3. $S(n) = S(n/2) + O(1)$ since if $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are stored in memory we don't have to allocate any additional memory at all for the recursive calls, and the output of $A$ is just one bit.

I believe the correct answer is (2), however I think one could make a case for (1) or (3) depending on the precise model of computation one is working in. Thoughts?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/50891/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/147848/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I noticed you got feedback on TCS.SE suggesting "to really pin down the space complexity, you'll probably need to specify more implementation details. Different implementations of this algorithm could have different space complexities. (E.g., how are the parameters to A passed, exactly?)".  If you'd like an answer, I encourage you to [edit] your question to provide that information.